# Unexpected Relative Phase while making the Toffoli Gate

Tags: quantum-gate, qiskit

I was trying to build the Toffoli gate using the following diagram (found in the qiskit textbook):
[image: qiskit book toffoli gate diagram]

So, I set `V := Rx(pi/2)` (as shown in the following diagram) (Note: that I am switching now to the little-endian format)
[image]

However, the unitary matrix equivalent to the previous was

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -i\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -i & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

That will lead to a relative phase of $(-i)$ in the states $\lvert 110 \rangle$ and $\lvert 111 \rangle$

What is the reason for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$R_x(\pi/2)$ isn't a square root of the X gate. If you square it, you get $-iX$ instead of $X$. That's where the phase is coming from.